# Relevance of using SonnarQube on coffeescript compiled JS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I m actually developping an application using coffeescript to transpile into javascript.

I was wondering if it's relevant to use SonnarQube to check generated javascript and to check unit test coverage % ?

Because when running sonar-runner on my ./app folder (the folder with the generated javascript), I have some errors and I can't do anything on these files.

Here's are some errors (due to coffeescript transpiling) :

[image]

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get away with some or all of the issues in your transpiled files by [setting up some exclusion rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues).

For instance, you can use a file pattern of `app/**/*.js` with a rule pattern of `*`, which will get rid of all issues on your transpiled files in the `app/` folder.

Now, if you only want coverage on your CoffeeScript code, you can have a look at the [generic coverage plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage), in conjunction with the `sonar.import_unknown_files` property - although this could generate some noise, depending on the types of files you have in your source tree.